# Python - Troubles sharing objects between processes using Manager.list

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I am trying to share some images between two Python processes using a Manager().list() object.
I have a main file, where I create and launch the processes:

main.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    set_start_method("spawn")

    # creating the list
    imgs_list = Manager().list()
    killing_switch = mp.Event()

    # creating the processes
    cam_reader = mp.Process(target=cam_reader_init, args=(killing_switch, imgs_list), daemon=True)
    cam_reader.start()

    frame_analyzer = mp.Process(target=frame_analyzer_init, args=(killing_switch, imgs_list), daemon=True)
    frame_analyzer.start()

    killing_switch.wait()
    sys.exit(0)
```

In cam_reader, I'm reading images from a video stream, and appending them to imgs_list:

```
# cam_reader

def cam_reader_init(killing_switch, imgs_list):
    cam_read = CamReader(killing_switch, imgs_list)
    cam_read.run()


class CamReader:

    def __init__(self, killing_switch, imgs_list):
        self.source = 0
        self.killing_switch = killing_switch
        self.imgs_list = imgs_list

    def run(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.source, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

        while True:
            # read frames and send them to imgs_list
            frame = None
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            if frame is not None:
                self.imgs_list.append(frame)
```

The problem is that I'm trying to access the frames that were sent to imgs_list in the other process:

```
# frame_analyzer

import cv2


def frame_analyzer_init(killing_switch, imgs_list):
    frame_analyzer = FrameAnalyzer(killing_switch, imgs_list)
    frame_analyzer.run()


class FrameAnalyzer:

    def __init__(self, killing_switch, imgs_list):
        self.killing_switch = killing_switch
        self.imgs_list = imgs_list

    def run(self):

        while True:
            if len(self.imgs_list) > 0:
                frame = self.imgs_list[-1]
                key = cv2.waitKey(1)
                if key == ord('q'):
                    print("done here")
                    self.killing_switch.set()
                    break
                cv2.imshow('frames', frame)
```

But, while in FrameAnalyzer, it appears that self.imgs_list is always empty (the len>0 condition is never met).

What am I missing?

EDIT: Using the debugger, I noticed the list in cam_reader is getting updated (images are appended to it), while the one in frame_analyzer stays always empty. Also, I saw that the 2 instances of the list in the two processes have different values of the _id field. Could this be the source of the issue? It does seem like the processes are using two different lists somehow.

Comment: The last 2 lines apear not under you `__main__` condition, fix their indentation and try again

Comment: It was a typo in the question here (not in the code). Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your OpenCV-related logic, it is important to `join` the subprocesses. If `join` is not used, the execution of the parent process will complete, resulting in the termination of the subprocesses' execution as well:

```
# main.py

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating the list
    imgs_list = Manager().list()

    # creating the processes
    cam_reader = mp.Process(target=cam_reader_init, args=(args, imgs_list), daemon=True)
    cam_reader.start()

    frame_analyzer = mp.Process(target=frame_analyzer_init, args=(args, imgs_list), daemon=True)
    frame_analyzer.start()

    cam_reader.join()
    frame_analyzer.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The minimal example I posted was a little too minimal, in the real code I'm using an event to avoid the issue you pointed out. I updated the question, to avoid further confusion.